# How to start Amazon DynamoDB Local automatically in SBT tests?

Tags: scala, sbt, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am trying to run a Scala test suite using [Amazon DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) via this plugin: https://github.com/localytics/sbt-dynamodb . It works, but only if I start DynamoDB Local manually on the command-line (`sbt start-dynamodb-local`). I would like it to start automatically whenever someone executes `sbt test` in the parent project directory. According to the docs:

> To have DynamoDB Local automatically start and stop around your tests
>
> ```
> startDynamoDBLocal := startDynamoDBLocal.dependsOn(compile in Test).value
> test in Test := (test in Test).dependsOn(startDynamoDBLocal).value
> testOptions in Test += dynamoDBLocalTestCleanup.value
> ```

but this just doesn't work:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:8000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve it with the following:

1. Move plugin reference `addSbtPlugin("com.localytics" % "sbt-dynamodb" % "1.4.3")` to the root project's `project/plugins.sbt`.
2. Qualify `compile` with `sbt.Keys.compile`.